# primary decomposition of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let G be the set of all pairs (x, y) of congruence classes x, y ∈ Z12 such that 4x + 6y = 0. Consider G as a subgroup of Z12 ⊕ Z12. Find the primary decomposition of G.

I know that the primary decomposition of Z12 ⊕ Z12 is $Z3\times Z3\times Z4\times Z4$. How do I incorporate the linear equation (looks like it is a Diophantine equation) in order to find the primary decomposition of the subgroup G of the group Z12 ⊕ Z12?

I know that ax+by=0 iff (-a/b)x implies a general solution of (x, (-a/b)x) iff (-bx, ax) where x is in the set of integers, so in this case, (-6x, 4x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}/12 \oplus \Bbb{Z}/12 \to \Bbb{Z}/12:(x,y)\mapsto 4x+6y$. Then $G$ is clearly the kernel of this homomorphism, and the image of this homomorphism is $2\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}$ which has order $6$.

Therefore, $G$ is an abelian group of order $24$ and is thus isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/3 \oplus (\Bbb{Z}/2)^3$,   $\Bbb{Z}/3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}/4 \oplus \Bbb{Z}/2$ or $\Bbb{Z}/3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}/8$. But, $G$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}/12 \oplus \Bbb{Z}/12$, in particular, it doesn't have any element of order $8$ and $(3,0)\in G$ has order $4$. So the only possibility is $$G \cong \Bbb{Z}/3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}/4 \oplus \Bbb{Z}/2.$$

Comment: Thanks @Nitrogen! where does (3,0) come from though?

Comment: What do you mean? It is an element of $G$ of order 4.

Comment: No i know that but why (3,0)? Where does the 0 come from?

Comment: Well, I wanted to find an element of order 4 and it's the first one that came to my mind.

Comment: Ah, ok got it. Thanks! Marking as solved.